# How to add outer glow on CAShapeLayer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I would like to create outer glow effect on CAShapeLayer which I animate later. Is this possible to achieve? I was looking at the documentation and can't find nothing similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use its `shadowColor`, `shadowOpacity`, and `shadowRadius` properties, with a `shadowOffset` of `(0,0)`. All of these properties are animatable via the usual CAAnimation malarkey.

Comment: awesome this is good. and is there any way to have line going throughout center of the stroke?

Comment: @boban0987 use the CALayer borderColor, borderWidth properties

Comment: when I create diagonal lines using CALayer, border sets for complete rectangle (all the way around my lines). I guess that this is not how it should be